# Problems with .exe file after converting it from .py. "ModuleNotFoundError: no module named 'selenium'"

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, pip, exe

Hear me out: Quite a newbie with Python. I totally may have messed up somewhere in this.

Here's the error message in full:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "webScrapingTool.py", line 1, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'
```

I wrote the code on Ubuntu 22.04, whose default Python version is 3.10.4. I have a dual-boot system. I had not realized that I *apparently*(?) needed to make a Windows executable directly in Windows, so I moved the file to there and tried. I downloaded Python for Windows, whose version is 3.12.2. As far as I understand, this is possibly part one of the problem.

Keep in mind that I have tried both 'pyinstaller' and 'auto-py-to-exe' on Ubuntu and I tried 'pyinstaller' on Windows too. When I create the executable in Windows, it will show the error message as above.

As mentioned, I am almost brand new to Python and I did a pretty basic project, but I really need to know what the issue is with finally making my file executable/usable for the average person.

When I try to do "pip install cx_freeze" or to install the 'requirements.txt' with pip, I get the error message like this:

https://pastebin.com/KheA21nM

The leads that I can give with this are that I'm almost certain that it is associated with where the program was written versus where the executable is being made (two different Python versions). I have seen a few pages that mentioned 'hiddenimports' in the .spec file, but no luck from what some suggested. Hopefully somebody knows exactly what I mean because while there are similar questions here, none of them are exactly like my situation here. Please let me know of anything that I can do to fix this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Description:

Inside the error focus on this line:

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": [url here - Reddit doesn't like links, so I removed it)
```

This indicates that you have to install or upgrade your previous version of [Microsoft Visual C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170#visual-studio-2015-2017-2019-and-2022). As C++ plays a vital role in converting your python file into a windows executable.

Secondly, if you familiar with manual library importing in pyinstaller, perform that action for the libraries that can't be installed by pyinstaller.

Comment: Hi! I did this, but I have a new error "no module named setuptools.extern.six". There's not a lot online regarding this issue. Have you ever experienced that one?

Comment: I made one pyinstaller file that wasn'even installing even a single package so I made it to not install any packages and when the exe was built completely I manually added them inside the exe`Lib` folder.

Comment: About the error you just sent I think u need to install `setuptools` first u can do that by `pip install setuptools` or as u mentioned that you are using `requirement.txt` add setuptools in that and try.

Comment: I have setuptools already. I searched online some, but not too many results about it. I read other posts about troubles when installing `extern`, so I tried installing that and `setup.extern`just in case, but no results too. I added `setuptools` in `requirements.txt`.

Comment: What about manual library addition?

Comment: The manual library addition worked! Thank you so much! I will give you the accepted answer status. You helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

you have to include project module before converting it

like:

```
pyinstaller.exe --onefile --hidden-import selenium  .\foo.py
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't go any differently for me. I received essentially the same error.

Comment: This may or may not still be necessary to get it working. The command format, at least. I upvoted as useful.